# JavaScript Traffic Light OnClick Using Switch/Case. Syntax or Logic Error?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm a GCSE student and new to JavaScript so I'm unsure to whether this is a logic or syntax error. The following code is supposed to cause a picture of a traffic light to change (from red to red amber, amber then green etc...) on the click of a button. 
I think the problem is with the condition of the switch expression. Have any ideas? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var Lights = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg"]
</script>
<img src="1.jpg" width="105" height="230" id="Red" alt="0">
<button type="button" id="Change" onclick="sequence()" >Change Light</button>
</head>
<script>
function sequence(){
    switch (document.getElementById("Red")){
    case "1.jpg":
        <img src="2.jpg" width="105" height="230" id="Red" alt="1">;
        break;
    case "2.jpg": 
        <img src="3.jpg" width="105" height="230" id="Red" alt="2">;
        break;
    case "3.jpg":
        <img src="4.jpg" width="105" height="230" id="Red" alt="3">;
        break;
    case "4.jpg": 
        <img src="1.jpg" width="105" height="230" id="Red" alt="0">;
        break;
        }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are encountering? I see only using HTML constructs (which is so illegal and strange...) in JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of basic mistakes: both logical and syntactic.

First, `document.getElementById("Red")` will return a DOM node. What you want to compare is the "src" attribute instead. This is a logical error.

Secondly, you will want to simply change that attribute's value as a result of each one of your cases. Currently your function makes no modification. Note that you also have a syntax error since each line following a case is not a valid expression.

So try something like this:

```
function sequence(){
    var image_tag = document.getElementById("Red");
    switch (image_tag.src){
        case "1.jpg":
            image_Tag.src = "2.jpg";
            image_Tag.alt = "1";
        break;
        case "2.jpg":
            image_Tag.src = "3.jpg";
            image_Tag.alt = "2";
        break;
        case "3.jpg":
            image_Tag.src = "4.jpg";
            image_Tag.alt = "3";
        break;
        case "4.jpg":
            image_Tag.src = "1.jpg";
            image_Tag.alt = "0";
        break;
    }
}
```

By the way, I'm not saying this is the best way to solve that problem. But this answer hopefully clarifies things enough that you can start about how to better code a solution. You can submit a post on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want somebody to suggest improvements to your corrected code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you actually want to do is to alter the src and the alt from the image, so all you have to do is document.getElementById("Red").src = number. the same for the alt property. You don't really need a switch statement here, junst a counter.
here is an example (working). I hope it can help you :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 var current = 1;
 function sequence(){
   var Lights = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png"]
   var maximum = Lights.length;
   if(current < maximum){
     current++;
   }else{
     current = 1;
   }
   console.log(current);//debug only
   document.getElementById("Red").src = current + ".png";    
   document.getElementById("Red").alt = current;
 }
</script>
<img src="1.png" width="105" height="230" id="Red" alt="0">
<button type="button" id="Change" onClick="sequence()" >Change     Light</button>
</head>
</html>
```